# How to find bad pixels on an image that has clusters of bad pixels?

Tags: c++, image-processing, pixel

I am working on a project in which my task is to find malfunctioning detector-pixels. I thought that this problem is really similar to the problems people facing, when trying to detect bad pixels on an image. Right now I have maps, that have good and bad detector pixels. The way to find out if a detector part is bad is the following: if collects different data then the other non-malfunctioning pixels around it, then it probably is malfunctioning. However, in my case, the bad pixels tend to be next to each other clumping up, and I don't really know how I should interpret this. Can someone help me out with a good algorithm, or a book that is helpful?

This is how a map looks:

[image: Example map]

These should be found:

[image: Exmple bad pixels]

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple images from the same sensor, and there are bad pixels at the same place, you can detect them by comparing images pixel by pixel. This will allow you to detect places that does not change (probably bad pixel).

Other idea may be using something like Gauss-Filter and then compare this blurred image with original one.

Good Idea will be loading some images to Gimp or Photoshop and try some filters and then if you will find good way to spot the bad pixels - implement it by yourself. I would recommend OpenCV for this task.

OpenCV has lots of build-in mechanism. Some of them (maybe edge-detection? blurring?) may be interesting for you.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I have datasets, that contain informations about the data each pixel collected. It can be high or really low, but if a detector part is malfunctioning then it is always going to collect less data. The different datasets have their malfunctioning detector parts on different places, and it cannot really be predicted where they should occur. Also their size vary from really small to big ones, so a simple blurring is not going to be a good method. I am going to look up this OpenCV though, looks useful, and c++ compatible :)